# Embedding a Google Earth KML into a webpage

Tags: wordpress, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, kmz

I've created a pretty large Google Earth project which includes several layers and features all of the protected areas in the Northern Brazilian Amazon, along with images and pop-up bubbles with relevant data. I'd now like to get my project online and am looking for ways to creatively do so since the Google Earth plugin gadget and API have been deprecated.

I have limited coding experience so ideally I'd like to embed the project into a wordpress, wix, etc. ready-made site.

Does anyone know of any alternative methods to get a Google Earth KML file onto a web page in a plugin window format?

Answer (score 2):

[Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) supports KML and has been the migration path for Google Earth Plugin web applications. Cesium can be used to create 2D map or 3D globe web applications.

There are several tutorials with over 30 Google Earth examples and demos ported to Cesium.

- https://cesiumjs.org/for-google-earth-developers.html
- https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/google-earth/Part-I/

You can view a comparison chart of Google Earth API and Cesium [here](https://cesium.com/blog/2015/01/27/migrating-from-earth-to-cesium/). You'll see that Cesium has a lot more features and capabilities than with Google Earth API. Cesium has a dynamic scene language called [CZML](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/CZML-Guide) that far surpasses what you can represent in standard KML. For all practical purposes, CZML is a super-set of KML and Cesium supports both data formats.